# Regex to remove /*...*/ comments from the start of the line

Tags: regex

I have some files of this type:

```
/*  78 */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   
/*  79 */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   
/*  eb */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   
/*  HG */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   
/*     */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
/*  83 */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   
/*  84 */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
/*     */ 
/*     */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
/*  ZX */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
/*     */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
/*     */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
/*  90 */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
/*  91 */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
/*  92 */     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

And I want to eliminate the

```
/*    */ 
/* 10 */
```

parts of text with regex, my regex looks like:

```
[/*(0-9)*/]
```

but it's not working properly, it deletes some texts containing numbers

Comment: You question is ambiguous, Do you want to eliminate all of the /*  */ comments, either if the contain letters/numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything inside `[` and `]` is called a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which will always match just a single character.

Inside a character class, the normal regex-meta-chars, like `*`, `(` and `)`, loose their special powers. So `[*]` matches just the literal `'*'`.

In your case, `[/*(0-9)*/]` will match one of the following chars: `'/'`, `'*'`,  `'('`,  `')'`,  `'/'` or any (ASCII) digit.

What you're looking for is the regex:

```
(?m)^/\*[\s0-9]*\*/
```

which matches a `"/*"` followed by zero or more space-chars (`\s`) or digits (`0-9`), ending with `"*/"`. The `^` matches the start of the input, and adding a `(?m)` in front of it makes it match the start of a line.

So it matches all multi-line comments from your example, except these:

```
/*  eb */
/*  HG */
/*  ZX */
```

Comment: Very nice explanation, but missing the start-of-line match, as the title says. You may want to use `^/\*[\s0-9]*\*/`.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: sorry, had not seen what you had put inside the brackets…

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression

```
/^\/\*[0-9\s]*\*\//
```

Or this expression if you want also to delete `/* AH */`

```
/^\/\*[\w\s]*\*\//
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, which matches the opening and closing /* and */ with some text in-between.

```
/^\/\*.*?\*\//
```

Comment: I think your expression also matches `/* 10 */ ..Some Text */`

Comment: @Fred, The `.*?` is a non-greedy match, so it should not match the text you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following regexp:

```
/\/\*.*?\*\//
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression

```
\/\*.*?\*\/\s+
```

`\/\*` matches the starting `/` and `*`

`.*?` matches any amount of text without being greedy

`\*\/` matches the ending `*` and `/`

`\s+` matches any amount of white space characters (optional)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux (or have access to it), you can do without regexes:

```
cut -b 10- <INPUTFILE>
```

Or if the strint is fixed width and on the beginngin of the line, with e.g. `sed`:

```
sed '/^.\{10\}//' <INPUTFILE>
```

Or with `awk` (if there are only two `/` on a line:

```
awk '{ print gensub(".*/","",1,$0) }'
```

HTH